# What does mean: Sunsetting a piece of software?

Tags: meaning, expressions, vocabulary

I found the expression *Sunsetting Atom* on https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/. What does it really mean?

Answer (score 3):

[Sunset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunset_(computing))

> In the realm of information technology (IT), to sunset a server, service, software feature, etc. is to plan to intentionally remove or discontinue it. In most cases, the term also connotes that this discontinuation is announced to users in advance, generally with an expected timeline.

It's an allusion to the sun going down in the evening - fading away

Comment: And it's a softer way of saying "We're cutting off support and leaving you in the dark".  In the case of software, the sun isn't expected to rise again.